# How to convert html to ASP.Net write.RenderBeginTag type code

Tags: c#, html

I have a nice set of html and now I need to use RenderBeginTag, RenderEndTag type of code in my custom control render method. Is there any tools for converting html C# code? It's just too much work for nothing, if I start coding this manually.

Comment: Hi Jani, welcome to stack overflow. Can you please post some code examples for what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "converting html C# code"?

Comment: Hi Oded

I want to convert something like
   <div class="title">Page title</div> 
to 
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "title");
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
    writer.Write("Page Title");
    writer.RenderEndTag();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to do this. The closest I could find was [this](http://www.jcbeck.com/features/tools/HTML2C.asp) site which generates HTML code into Response.Write calls.

Answer (score 0):

When writing custom `WebControl` classes, you can still use standard ASP.NET controls, avoiding the need to use the tag rendering methods:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyCustomControl runat=server></{0}:MyCustomControl>")]
public class MyCustomControl : CompositeControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {

    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["Text"];
            return ((o == null) ? "Set my text!" : (string)o);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Text"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        // Create controls
        var label = new Label();
        label.ID = "innerLabel";
        label.Text = this.Text;

        // Add controls
        this.Controls.Add(label);

        // Call base method
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
}
```

Or you can use the tags in the render methods like so:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyCustomControl runat=server></{0}:MyCustomControl>")]
public class MyCustomControl : CompositeControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {

    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderEndTag(writer);

        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            var label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Hello!";
            label.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this answers your question :s

Comment: This leads to same problem. I have something like 10 different page layouts with few hundred lines of html. Instead of writing RenderTags I would have to write code like

Table t = new Table();
this.Control.Add(t);
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
t.Rows.Add(tr);

It don't get my any closer to my original target. If somebody knows how to create this type of code from html, is also a good option.

Jani

Answer (score 0):

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyCustomControl runat=server></{0}:MyCustomControl>")]
public class MyCustomControl : CompositeControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {

    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderEndTag(writer);

        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            var label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Hello!";
            label.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy and paste my answer?